# При запуске gulp в терминале появляется ошибка: Error in plugin 'sass'. Error: Invalid CSS after "...": expected "{", was ";"

Tags: gulp, sass

### Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться:

При запуске gulp в терминале появляется ошибка:

> Error in plugin 'sass'
>
> Message:
>
> catalog/view/theme/delivery/stylesheet/_media.sass
>
> Error: Invalid CSS after "...-width : 768px)": expected "{", was ";"
>           on line 17 of catalog/view/theme/delivery/stylesheet/_media.sass @media only screen
>   and (max-width : 768px);

*Скриншот терминала:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/prTWC.jpg

**gulpfile.js:**

```
var gulp           = require('gulp'),
    gutil          = require('gulp-util' ),
    sass           = require('gulp-sass'),
    browserSync    = require('browser-sync'),
    cleanCSS       = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    autoprefixer   = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    bourbon        = require('node-bourbon'),
    ftp            = require('vinyl-ftp');


gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync({
        proxy: "http://localhost:8888/opencart.loc/",
        notify: false
    });
});

gulp.task('sass', function() {
  return gulp.src('catalog/view/theme/delivery/stylesheet/stylesheet.sass')
    .pipe(sass({
        includePaths: bourbon.includePaths
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions']))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('catalog/view/theme/delivery/stylesheet/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream: true}))
});

gulp.task('watch', ['sass', 'browser-sync'], function() {
    gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/delivery/stylesheet/stylesheet.sass', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/delivery/template/**/*.tpl', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/delivery/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('catalog/view/theme/delivery/libs/**/*', browserSync.reload);
});
```

*Скриншот файла media.sass:* https://i.stack.imgur.com/8flJT.jpg

Файл stylesheet.css не создается.

Comment: Могу ошибаться, но возможно ошибка в табулации. Попробуйте очистить 18 строку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы указываете *@media*, но не описываете их. Синтаксис требует операторные скобки. Если вы, по какой-то причине, не хотите описывать стили для этих размеров, добавьте, по крайней мере, пустые скобки к каждому *@media*:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {}
```

Comment: я использую препроцессор SASS, данные скобки не нужны.

Comment: Тогда в строке 18 вам надо проставить отступ и любое содержимое, например `/**/`, как это сделано в остальных _@media_

Comment: вы правы, спасибо, вопрос решен.

Comment: @Seger, если ответ вам помог отметьте его решением и поставьте галку слева от ответа.